# Cannot POST /api/users/register - Error 404

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

After running the react app and registering the data on the register page, 'Cannot POST /api/users/register' error is showing up in the console. The database is not taking any data and we are not able to register the user.

//Backend Code

server.js

```
const express = require("express");
const path = require("path");
const app = express();
const dbConnection = require("./Db/db");
app.use(express.json());

const port = process.env.PORT || 8000;

app.use("/api/cars/", require("./Routes/carsRoutes"));
//refresh error
app.use("/booking/api/cars/", require("./Routes/carsRoutes"));
app.use("/editcar/api/cars/", require("./Routes/carsRoutes"));
app.use("/api/users/", require("./Routes/usersRoutes"));
app.use("/booking/api/bookings/", require("./Routes/bookingsRoute"));
app.use("/api/bookings/", require("./Routes/bookingsRoute"));
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "production") {
  app.use(express.static("client/build"));

  app.get("*", (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, "client", "build", "index.html"));
  });
}
app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Server is running at port: ${port} `);
});
```

db.js

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

function connectDb() {
  mongoose.connect("mongodb+srv://abc:123@abcd.xmqfw5n.mongodb.net/?retryWrites=true&w=majority", {
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
    useNewUrlParser: true,
  });
  const connection = mongoose.connection;
  connection.on("connected", () => {
    console.log("connection successfull");
  });
  connection.on("error", () => {
    console.log("connection failed");
  });
}

connectDb();
module.exports = mongoose;
```

userController.js

```
const User = require("../Models/userModal");
exports.login = async (req, res) => {
  const { email, password } = req.body;
  try {
    const user = await User.findOne({ email, password });
    if (user) {
      res.send(user);
    } else {
      return res.status(400).json(error);
    }
  } catch (error) {
    return res.status(400).json(error);
  }
};
exports.register = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const newuser = new User(req.body);
    await newuser.save();
    res.send("User registered successfully");
  } catch (error) {
    return res.status(400).json(error);
  }
};
```

userModel.js

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  username: { type: String, required: true },
  password: { type: String, required: true },
  email: { type: String, required: true },
  phone: { type: String },
  admin: {
    type: Boolean,
    default: false,
  },
});

const userModel = mongoose.model("users", userSchema);

module.exports = userModel;
```

userRoutes.js

```
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();
const userController = require("../Controllers/userController");
router.post("/login", userController.login);
router.post("/register", userController.register);
module.exports = router;
```

//Frontend

client/userActions.js

```
import axios from "axios";
import { message } from "antd";

export const userLogin = (reqObj) => async (dispatch) => {
  dispatch({ type: "LOADING", payload: true });

  try {
    const response = await axios.post("/api/users/login", reqObj);
    const { admin, username, _id } = response.data;
    localStorage.setItem("user", JSON.stringify({ admin, username, _id }));
    message.success("Login success");
    dispatch({ type: "LOADING", payload: false });
    setTimeout(() => {
      window.location.href = "/";
    }, 500);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    message.error("Something went wrong");
    dispatch({ type: "LOADING", payload: false });
  }
};

export const userRegister = (reqObj) => async (dispatch) => {
  dispatch({ type: "LOADING", payload: true });

  try {
    await axios.post("/api/users/register", reqObj);
    message.success("Registration successfull");
    setTimeout(() => {
      window.location.href = "/login";
    }, 500);

    dispatch({ type: "LOADING", payload: false });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    message.error("Something went wrong");
    dispatch({ type: "LOADING", payload: false });
  }
};
```

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: `require("./Routes/usersRoutes"))` vs `userRoutes.js`. **Typo**?

Comment: yeah the file name is 'usersroutes' only. It is still showing the same error.

Answer (score 1):

I see the name of the user router file (`userRoutes.js`) is not match with which you import in `server.js`.
You should change to
`app.use("/api/users/", require("./Routes/userRoutes"));`

Comment: yeah the file name is 'usersroutes' only. It is still showing the same error.